# Avoid boilerplate code when initializing collection properties in c#

Tags: c#, properties, boilerplate

Is there a way to avoid writing exactly the same type twice when initializing properties (or fields) in c#? (something similar to diamond operator in Java would do..)

For example, lets say I have this code:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, ISomething> _dict = 
                  new Dictionary<string, ISomething>();
```

Is there a way to avoid writing the type `Dictionary<string, ISomething>()` or part of it twice?

Please note that the type is already defined as `Dictionary`, not `IDictionary`..

Comment: No, not really.  Although a good IDE will autocomplete / auto-predict most of it for you.

Comment: After having learned F#, this kind of seemingly senselessly repeated type information, which the compiler should be perfectly able to infer, always threatens to drive me insane… :) In F#, no 'good IDE' is required; you simply write ``let private _dict = Dictionary<string, ISomething> ()``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's nothing like that in C# at the moment. The obvious potential fix would be to allow fields to be declared using `var`, but that's [more complicated than it may sound](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/).

I'd be somewhat surprised to see anything like Java's "diamond operator" appear in C#, but I've been surprised before...

If you're really trying to avoid the *typing* then I'd expect Visual Studio to help offer to complete the assignment after you type `new`. (Personally I don't view typing as the main bottleneck when coding anyway, but...)

Comment: Out of interest, could you elaborate on why you don't think the diamond operator will be introduced/isn't a good idea?

Comment: Well, diamond operator is just a shorthand for declaring type parameters in Java generics, but I may have surprised if C# has similar syntax `var list = new List<>()` which automatically points to `List<object>` type.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: It adds significant complexity, given that `<>`, `<,>` is already used in `typeof`. (I'd like it to be available for `nameof` too.) It would be slightly odd for `Dictionary<,>` to mean one thing in `typeof` and a different thing in an `new` expression. I'm probably more sensitive to the "adds complexity to the language specification" cost than most people though :)

Comment: Right I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be simplified, not sure if that is what you are looking for

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, ISomething> _dict = 
                  new Dictionary<string, ISomething>();
```

As follows

```
Using MyCustomDict = Dictionary<string, ISomething>;


private readonly MyCustomDict  _dict = new MyCustomDict();
```

And MyCustomDict can be used instead of Dictionary<string, ISomething> throughout the page.